# Is there a way how to use [switch] parameter in Azure Runbook

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a small script I'm migrating to Azure Automation account as Azure Runbook. 
Originally, the script was using some switch parameters for example -WhatIf.

```
#Requires -Version 3.0 
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
 #//Other parameters
[switch]$WhatIf
 #//Other parameters
)
if ($WhatIf.IsPresent) {
 #////Do something
}
```

But when I try to test it in the test pane I'm not able to pass any value into it.

[image]

I tried 1,0, $True, $true, True, False but nothing seems working. I know I can change the type of the parameter, but I was wondering there might be a better way. Is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst you can use Switch parameters in Azure Automation Runbooks, the best practice advice is to use [bool] instead.  You can default it to false, and even check if it's been passed in (if you want/need to for any reason).  This would make your function look as follows:

```
#Requires -Version 3.0 
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
    [bool]$WhatIf
)

# Check if user supplied $WhatIf parameter
if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('WhatIf')) {
    # User specified -WhatIf
} else {
    # User did not specify -WhatIf
}

# Simple parameter check - can't differentiate between $false supplied by user and parameter not supplied
if ($WhatIf) {
    # User specified -WhatIf
} else {
    # User did not specify -WhatIf
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just specify the value **true** or **false** without any single/double quotes or any other decorations. It will work fine in AA Runbooks. Discovered it the hard ay myself after finding no guidance around same on Web.

However, like @AndyHerb mentioned, the best practice is to use a bool type instead of switch in an AA Runbook, because it makes thing easier.

HTH...

Comment: It's also worth nothing that "true" and "false" must be in lower case. Thank you very much!